# STM32F4 Timer accuracy

Tags: stm32, timer, stm32f4

I'm working with an STM32F4 Discovery board and I've come across a bit of unusual behavior that I'm hoping someone can explain the cause of to me. My goal is to configure a timer to trigger an interrupt at 100 Hz (i.e. 10 ms period). It's important for my project to have this value be as close to 10 ms as possible. My system clock is configured at 168 MHz, and the timer I'm using is clocked on the APB2 bus, which is clocked at 84 MHz, but since timers operate at double their bus's clock speed, my timer's clock is effectively also at 168 MHz.

To get my period of 10 ms, I would have to configure my prescaler and period values in the TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef struct to 16-bit integer values. The initial values I chose were 60000 for the prescaler, and 28 for the period. 168 MHz / 60K = 2800 Hz. Then setting my period to 28 should give me an update event at 100 Hz.

I'm fairly positive that my math checks out, however, when I measured out the time when my interrupt was firing, my period was something closer to 10.33 ms, rather than the expected 10 ms. After playing around with other settings, I decided to try and change the prescaler and period values to see if the timing settings changed. To my surprise, they did. For the period values that I did try, I plotted them out in this plot below: [image: scatterchart]

Two main observations that I see:

1) Swapping the period for the prescaler and vice versa results in the same measured period

2) The closer the period and prescaler values are to each other, the closer the measured time is to the desired period.

Does anyone know why this is? It seems to me there's no difference between the pair (60000,28) and (1344,1250) in terms of calculating the period (i.e. they both multiply to 1680000)

Edit: I've added a link to my code [here](http://pastebin.com/WNaW4pr2).

Edit2: I feel like the comments are deviating from my intended question. My issue isn't that I can't get a 10 ms period. My question is WHY setting the prescaler and period to values further apart from each other results in a less accurate period?

Comment: Mate, i think you are having integer overflow? The max number  for 16 bit unsigned integer is 65,535. You should cast all numbers and operations that need to result in larger than this to an unsigned long.

Comment: @KyranF Thanks for the reply. I'm skeptical that it's an issue of integer overflow. I specifically made sure that the largest prescaler value I worked with was 60,000, which is within range?

Comment: Okay, indeed this is not the issue then. What is your clock being generated from? Perhaps there are tolerance/% inaccuracy issues here that you can directly see from the timer's output?

Comment: @KyranF There's an 8 MHz crystal being used as the HSE clock. It's the one that's already mounted on the STM32F4 Discovery board

Comment: Are you sure it's an unsigned int (max value ~65000) and not a signed int (max value ~32000)?

Comment: Hm... well 10.33 is 3.3% off from the correct value, maybe that is actually within tolerance? Can you find a value, even if it doesnt seem right, that actually DOES get to the 10.0ms?

Comment: Yes, when I choose a prescaler and period value that are close to one another (1344 and 1250 are the best I can do), I can get a period of 10.007 ms, which is sufficient for my purposes. I'm more curious as to why the measured period gets longer the further apart the prescaler and period values are from each other.

Comment: @Kyran.  **NO**.  This platform has a 32-bit `int`, not a 16-bit one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is true, but the timers are 16 bit counters. The prescaler and auto-reload registers are also 16-bit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton did you read this bit "To get my period of 10 ms, I would have to configure my prescaler and period values in the TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef struct to 16-bit integer values", because I did! This may have something to do with it, but it seems that his numbers are not being multipled/added to go above the max value for 16 bit unsigned int, so I doubt this is the case anyway.

Comment: @HD_Mouse how are you taking your measurements?  And are you measuring from the previous occurrence, or cumulative from the start time, or number of occurrence per unit time?  You should expect some *jitter* in instance-to-instance measurements due to interrupt latency and other possibly higher priority interrupts, but error should average out, not accumulate over time.

Comment: @HD_Mouse if your 'calculated' times and prescaler values are not working out as intended, there is something wrong or low tolerance somewhere, I guess. If people want ulta accurate timing they usually rely on external sources like RTC

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to check right now, but I am thinking that you need to subtract 1 from timer and prescaler calculated settings. I have to go ...

Comment: @Tut you are absolutely correct, if that is not already being done.  As for the 16 vs 32 bit issue, math will be done as a (32-bit) `int` unless other source types are specified, then the *result* will be truncated to the target register size.  So no casting is needed - the only concern is if the result exceeds the register width.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have GPIO pins configured in my ISR to go high when the ISR is entered and then go low at the end of the ISR. The time measurement is taken using a logic analyzer to measure the time between rising edges. Jitter is definitely expected, but a consistent 0.3 ms increase is a bit much?

Comment: @Tut Yes, That's already being done in my code. I left that out for clarity. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Are you sure??? Running the math, Tut's "off by one" theory fits your data quite well.

Comment: Yes I'm quite positive. Give me a moment, I'll share the timer configuration code in a pastebin...

Comment: You only compensated the prescaler, not the period.  The difference between 27 (which would be 28) vs 28 (which becomes 29) is the source of your extra ~.3 ms.

Comment: To address your update - conversely, the difference between 1344 vs 1345 and 1249 vs 1250 isn't very much, so off-by-one produces only a small error there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you would post it as an answer, I can accept it to make it more visible.

Comment: Let's see if we can get @Tut back here to claim credit for first mentioning the issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks ... I really am not going to have a chance to make a proper answer and you have put far more time into this than I. Please feel free to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tut was first to suggest, the observed error arrises from the fact that the total number of cycles in these dividers is one more than the value loaded into the corresponding register.

You took this into account in the prescaler register, but not in the period register.

When you apportion the net division equitably between the two stages, each has a moderately large value and so the effect of "off-by-one" is small.

But when you apportion the division unequally such that one value is only 28, the difference between 29 counts (28+1) vs the correct 28 (27+1) is responsible for the 1-part-in-28 error you see.

Answer (score 2):

It actually divide frequency as:

$$ f = \frac{168~MHz}{(60000+1)\cdot(28+1)} = 96.55~Hz \\ T = 10.36~ms $$

If you want 10Hz, please try to set prescaler = 59999, period = 27; 
then the timer will work as

$$ f = \frac{168~MHz}{(59999+1)\cdot(27+1)} = 100~Hz $$

It's a rule from STM specification.